# Options to store Large Configuration Data in an AppExchange Managed Package

Tags: governorlimits, appexchange, largedatavolumes, storage-limit

We have an AppExchange App which needs to connect with an external application via API Calls. API calls need to happen in individual user context and not in a single Integration User context.
This means to use the External API, every user has to authenticate once to the external application and their Access Token/Refresh Token needs to be stored in salesforce. The number of users can be more than 5k.
To store access token/refresh token in a secure way, we are aware of the below options:

1. Protected custom setting- 3MB size limit per certified AppExchage package.
2. Protected metadata type- 10 million characters.
3. Platform cache- 10 MB size limit(depends on edition).
4. Protected custom object - No documentation found on limits.

One approach for the long term would be to store encrypted tokens in a custom object and use a protected custom setting to hold an encryption key.
**Questions:**

1. Can we increase the protected custom setting size limit as per requirements?
2. Is it safe to use a custom object to store access/refresh token in an encrypted format?
3. Is there any limitation on using the protected custom object?
4. What are the other options available to store access/refresh tokens, when data size is unknown?